# Get Primary Key identifier of static block (integer not string)

Tags: blocks, ce-1.9.1.0, model

In magento 1.9.1:

I'm building a system that includes a table with a FK pointing to a static block ID ( see cms_block table in Magento, that's the table I'm correlating to ).  For the system to work dependably, I need to be able to store a record referencing the primary key on the cms_block table.

Put simply:  I need a variation of `$block->getBlockId()` that always returns the primary key (an integer) associated with the static block in question.

It seems, as far as I can tell, `$myBlock->getBlockId()` returns an integer *only* if the block is invoked with an integer.  If the block is invoked with its corresponding identifier string (a common scenario), it returns the identifier string instead.

Is there a way for me to get at that primary key without having to talk to the database directly?

**Answer**

Props to Rajeev K Tomy :)

Here is my code that got the job done:

```
    $model = Mage::getModel( 'cms/block' );
    $collection = $model->getCollection()
        ->addFieldToFilter( 'identifier', $this->getBlockId() );

    $block = $collection->getFirstItem();

    return $block->getId();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the primary key of static block

```
/** $block Mage_Cms_Model_Block **/
$block->getId()
```